# Razor to print a div every 12 elements

Tags: c#, razor

I have a collection of items and would like to print them out with Razor. For every 12 elements it should create a new div. However, opening and closing tags seems to cause a lot of problems. This is my code.

```
<div class='grid_7'>
@foreach (var property in properties)
{

    @if (counter % 12 == 0)
    {
    </div>
    <div class='grid_7'>
    }

    @if (property.ShowInEditor)
    {
    <span> one property! @(property.Name) </span>
    }

    counter++
}
```

However, it is telling me that the first `if` and the first `foreach` are missing a closing `{`. I think that's because of the unclosed tags but, as you can see, I can't close the tag there.

How can I do this?

edit: removing `@` before the `if` cause even more problems making Razor belive it is text and not code.

Comment: You are missing a ';' after counter++

Comment: There should be modulo by 7

Comment: Damn, you're right... I meant 12 not 7... Got confused by the div grid class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "@:" without the quotes before the lines where you get this error and remove the `@` before if statements.

```
<div class='grid_7'>

@foreach (var property in properties)
{

    if (counter % 12 == 0)
    {
    @:</div>
    @:<div class='grid_7'>
    }

    if (property.ShowInEditor)
    {
    @:<span> one property! @property.Name </span>
    }

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: cool, it is working but I also have to change some other stuff. Will edit your answer.

Comment: This won't work completely, as you will get an empty div class at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @Digbyswift Do you mean if there are no elements in 'properties' then we would end with a '<div class='grid_7'>' without a closing '</div>' ?

Comment: No, if there *are* items in properties, because `counter` is likely to start off as zero, 0%7 = 0, so on the first iteration of the loop, it will render out an empty div.

Comment: @Digbyswift Well, since there is no explicit mention by the OP about the initial value of counter, I am not sure how accurate that assumption might be. I see your point though.

Comment: The OP says every 12 elements, so `count` must start at zero (or a multiple of 12) otherwise the first set of loops will create a collection of less than 12 elements.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to modify your conditions a little to take into account the counter being zero at the start otherwise you'll get an empty div on first interation:

```
<div class='grid_7'>

@{
    var counter = 0;

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {

        if (counter > 0 && counter % 12 == 0)
        {
            @Html.Raw("</div><div class='grid_7'>")
        }

        if (property.ShowInEditor)
        {
            <span> one property! @(property.Name) </span>
        }

        counter++;
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='grid_7'>
    @foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (count%7==0)
        {
            @Html.Raw("</div>");
            @Html.Raw("<div class='grid_7'>");
        }

        else 
        {
            //do something 
        }
```